# How can I install ubuntu using USB startup disk creator

Tags: boot

I have ubuntu-9.04 version. I am supposed to install a newer version of Ubuntu. For that I downloaded ubuntu-12.04, but when I install this version using USB startup disk creator and put it in USB and restart the PC and start to boot with USB it does not work. How should I proceed?

Comment: mm... can you be more specific... what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `UNetbootin`. You can burn USB drive (create LiveUSB) using this and then boot using that USB. It should work.
You can even download and burn USB using this software. I think the software is available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/latest/download).

Answer (score 0):

If you see black screen and blinking cursor _ and nothing happens when you try to boot from usb - try use some other usb flash drive and use UNetbootin to make bootable usb flash drive

Comment: good answer but how can I install UNebootin

Answer (score 0):

This guide describes how to make a dual boot system when Windows already exists on it.

A typical Ubuntu installation alongside Windows will go as follows:

- Insert Ubuntu installation disk (LiveUSB) in the system and boot from it.
- Choose Install Ubuntu when asked to either try or install it.
- Select language
- When Preparing to Install window appears, it will present you with following options

  - **Install Ubuntu alongside your other systems** (e.g. alongside Windows). Select this option in your case.
  - Erase disk and install Ubuntu (Install Ubuntu over your entire hard drive).
  - Something else (use manual options for installations, like partitioning hard drive and then install).

Here is a [graphical step-by-step installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall#continueinstall) for dual booting Windows and Ubuntu. A more detailed Wiki is available [here](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aAll#Dual-Booting_Windows_and_Ubuntu).

**Unetbootin :**

If you need to use tools like`UNetbootin`, you can download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/latest/download).

If you are encountering any specific errors during installation, please mention them here.